# How to Create Elevator in Gazebo with Control ROS Topics?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to create scenario in Gazebo with elevator. I can use [ElevatorPlugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=elevators&cat=plugins) that is working but I don't control elevator by ros topics. How can i control ros topics that elevator ?

This is [elevator.world.](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/elevator.world?fileviewer=file-view-default)
and also this is [gazebo plugin of elevator.](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_elevator.cpp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298423/how-to-create-elevator-in-gazebo-with-control-ros-topics-?/) by [Onur](https://answers.ros.org/users/36628/onur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not familiar with this code and haven't used it, but I can read through it and explain what it's doing.

The callback type is `std_msgs/String`: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_elevator.cpp#L80 , but it calls `std::strtoi` on the argument, which indicates that the string should be a number.

The topic name is defined by the `<topic>` XML property: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_elevator.cpp#L60-L61

This sets the topic to `~/elevator`: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/elevator.world?fileviewer=file-view-default#elevator.world-196 . That's relative to the gazebo node name, so probably `/gazebo/elevator` . Running `rostopic list` when the elevator simulation and looking for a topic with "elevator" in the name will also help you find the topic name.

Overall, it looks like publishing "1" or "2" (or maybe "0", if floors are 0-indexed) on the `/gazeo/elevator` topic (or whatever topic it's actually using) will send the elevator to a floor.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Onur](https://answers.ros.org/users/36628/onur/) on 2018-07-25**:
Thanks for advise. While running launch file, I looked to elevator topics but i didn't see. Also i looked `rosnode list` but i didn't see anything about elevator.

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2022-04-10**:
I have the same problem. Did you find the answer?